# Maven CLI Compilation Error: No compiler is provided in this environment

Tags: maven, maven-compiler-plugin

I am compiling a simple maven application using `mvn compile`on Solaris server from terminal and I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project maven-demo: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
```

JAVA_HOME points to /home/userName/Java/jdk1.8.0_201

All the solutions I found involved eclipse preferences. I need to compile it from the terminal, Any help please ?

Update: 
this is the output of `mvn -version`

```
Apache Maven 3.6.0 (97c98ec64a1fdfee7767ce5ffb20918da4f719f3; 2018-10-24T20:41:47+02:00)
Maven home: /home/userName/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.0
Java version: 1.8.0_112, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.8.0/jre
Default locale: en, platform encoding: ISO646-US
OS name: "sunos", version: "5.11", arch: "sparcv9", family: "unix"
```

Comment: Please add the output of `mvn -version`

Comment: check the output added in the question

Comment: JAVA_HOME is not set correctly currently maven picks up a different java version (1.8.0_112). What does `echo $JAVA_HOME` return?

Comment: /home/userName/Java/jdk1.8.0_201

Comment: I've never used Solaris so from this point on your guess is as good as mine. But maybe these are helpful: 
https://blogs.oracle.com/taylor22/javahome-on-solaris-11
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36802/gnztu.html

Answer (score -2):

---

> ***If your using Linux/Red-hat version then only***

---

--> `yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless.x86_64`

--> `yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64`

--> `update-alternatives --config java #pick java 1.8` and press 1

--> `update-alternatives --config javac #pick java 1.8` and press 2

Thank You

Comment: It specifically mentions Solaris as the OS and this is not so much the installation of java put setting up maven (JAVA_HOME) that is the problem.